# C# - Deserialize XML to an Object given Full Class Name

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

What is the proper way to deserialize XML into an instance of a class given that I have the full name of the class (as a string) and the XML (as a string)? One caveat, I'm doing this work in one assembly and the business object I want to deserialize to is in another referenced assembly.

Comment: I think you can make your life a lot easier if you make an instance of the deserializer in the assembly where the business object resides, rather than the other way around.

Comment: so you have no control over biz object? and how is the XML serialized? some custom serialization or XmlSerializer?

Answer (score 2):

```
  using (StringReader strreader = new StringReader("xml of the object"))
        {
            using (XmlReader xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(strreader))
            {
                dynamic result = new XmlSerializer(Type.GetType("your type")).ReadObject(xmlreader);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the class name, but rather have a reference to the class type.

Then you can deserialize the XML like so:

```
StringReader read = new StringReader(xmlOfAnObject);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(myObject.GetType());
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(read);

WhateverTheType myObject = (WhateverTheType) serializer.Deserialize(reader);

reader.Close();
read.Close();
read.Dispose();
```

Comment: actually in my use case I will have the XML as a string and the name of the full class in another string.

Comment: You need a reference to the assembly that contains the actual class and references to any dependencies of that class. If all you have is the string, and you can derive where the assembly is, then you can use Reflection + the XML Deserializer.

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Deserialize string XML to the object of type T.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object where the xmlText are deserialized.</typeparam>
/// <param name="xmlText">The xml string to be deserialized to the object of type T.</param>
public static T DeserializeXMLToObject<T>(string xmlText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlText)) return default(T);
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(xmlText)))
    using (XmlTextReader xsText = new XmlTextReader(memoryStream))
    {
        xsText.Normalization = true;
        return (T)xs.Deserialize(xsText);
    }
}
```

You need the type of the XML you want to deserialize.